# Bind static variable (out of scope) to html in Angular / typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I created a little test typescript/angularjs website.

I have this module with a static variable which I want to bind to the html-document so that I can see the current logged-in user.

```
module mytest.constants {

    export class CurrentSession {

        public static CURRENT_USER: string = "Tobi";

    }
}
```

the problem is:
the current scope is a controller which is separated from my CurrentSession-class.

I would like to do something like

```html
<div class="label" style="color:green">
  Logged in as: {{mytest.constants.CurrentSession.CURRENT_USER}}
</div>
```

Another way I could do is to add a class-member to the controller and set it in constructor like:

```
this.CurrentUSer = mytest.constants.CurrentSession.CURRENT_USER
```

but I would prefer to bind the static-variable directly to the html-file.

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you dfsq for your quick answer.

I finally found another solution.

I first set a variable called "CurrentSession" in my app.ts and set the value to a new Instance of my Object

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .constant("CurrentSession", new mytest.constants.CurrentSession())
```

then I can just inject this Constant in my controller like this:

```
export class MainCtrl {

    public static $inject = ["$state", "$http", "CurrentSession"];

    constructor($state, $http, private CurrentSession) {
      ...
    }
```

the good thing here is, that I can use the "private CurrentSession" which will automatically set the a member-variable "CurrentSession".

The html looks like this:

```html
<button ng-click="main.logOut()">Log out {{main.CurrentSession.CURRENT_USER.Name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't bind static properties like this, Angular just doesn't check those in its digest cycle. You can however create a scope/this reference to the class itself. Something like this:

```
module mytest.constants {

    export class CurrentSession {

        public static CURRENT_USER: string = "Tobi";

        CurrentSession = CurrentSession;

    }
}
```

So basically it will create own property like `this.CurrentSession = CurrentSession`.

Then in template (assuming you are using controllerAs syntax with `session` refer to controller instance) you would be able to bind `CURRENT_USER` as

```html
<div>{{session.CurrentSession.CURRENT_USER}}</div>
```